What is the grammatical gender of the novel "Don Quijote"?
What is the grammatical gender of the novel "Don Quijote"?
I know that the famous novel's protagonist is male, so the gender is masculine if one refers to the person. But what if one discusses the novel (the literary work)?
Some simple frequency searches online seem to demonstrate that "Don Quijote fue escrito" is more common than "Don Quijote fue escrita", but as a beginner I'm not sure whether I'm interpreting the results correctly.
I would expect the feminine gender if things worked the same as for geographical entities, because "obra de arte" (work of art) and "novela" (novel) are both feminine. Are titles simply interpreted as if they were ordinary noun phrases? In that case the gender of "Don Quijote (de la Mancha)" would of course be that of "Don Quijote"-the-person, namely masculine.

I'm a beginner too. I would say that it depends whether:


the sentence "Don Quijote fue escrito" is referring to the Don Quijote as "el libro" (the book) -> masculine;


the sentence "Don Quijote fue escrita" is referring to the Don Quijote as "la obra de literatura"  (the literature work) o "la obra maestra" (the masterpiece) o "la novela" (the novel) -> feminine.
Maybe someone else can confirm.



La verdad es que no tengo respuesta. Yo veo que ambos podrían ir bien, pero señal cual fuere la respuesta eso ya te da información de que no nos preocupamos por los géneros de los nombres a menos que por ejemplo se trate de una persona en concreto

@tac Thanks for your response. Even if you are right, there is still the question whether (1) the gender only depends on the imagined category or (2) titles can or often are interpreted like ordinary noun phrases (like what I suggest at the bottom).

Un sustantivo y un adjetivo tienen género gramatical, pero una «frase nominal ordinaria» no. Si utilizas «la novela, la película, el libro, ...» antes del título, entonces no se plantea tu problema.

Novels don't have genders. Genres of literature do. La obra Don Quijote, la novela Don Quijote, el personaje de Don Quijote etc. Can you see it now?

It should be noted that the novel Don Quijote is often referred as "El Quijote" - while its main character is always referred Don Quijote. That use of "El Quijote", which I suppose informal in origin but it's common in formal settings, may mark the gender of that novel as masculine, and that may make this novel a non representative example of the grammatical gender of artworks.

Minor note: the first novel (i.e.., first part) was entitled "El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha". The title of the second novel is "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha".

No sé muy bien como funciona porque honestamente nunca nos enseñan a ponerle género a los nombres. El criterio que aplicaría es el de asignarle el mismo género que el del sustantivo más cercano al que refiere el nombre. Es decir, en principio depende de la categoría imaginada pero no siempre hay tanta libertad para imaginar. Con personas es trivial y muy restrictivo, porque el nombre de la persona recibiría el mismo género que el de la persona que lo posea.
En mi opinión, tu ejemplo es algo engañoso, porque Don Quijote es también el nombre del protagonista, entonces la gente va a tener la tendencia a asociarlo con el nombre de la persona―sobre todo siendo algo tan antiguo y tan asentado en la cultura general―es decir, entre ‘libro’ y ‘novela’ van a preferir lo primero entonces queda masculino. Tenemos Don Quijote ~ protagonista (hombre) -> libro. Por lo tanto, decir ‘Don Quijote fue escrita en tal año (la novela)’ no lo doy por incorrecto aunque sería muy raro de escuchar.
Después para los demás casos en general hay una cierta libertad, pensando ejemplos se me viene:

Ayer vi El Zorro, está buenísima! (la película)
Ayer vi El Zorro, está buenísimo! (el film, el personaje)
Ayer leí Tuya, está buenísima! (la novela)
Ayer leí Tuya, está buenísimo! (el libro)
Ayer vi Dragon Ball Z, está buenísimo! (el ánime)
Ayer vi Dragon Ball Z, está buenísima! (la saga)

Todo depende de tu capacidad para imaginar cuál es el sustantivo que corresponda, aunque hay cosas que son difíciles de asociar y van a sonar muy raro. Tal es el caso del último ejemplo, ya que es muy raro que alguien asocie un nombre con una saga antes de haberlo asociado con un ánime. Espero que te haya ayudado a esclarecer en algo tu duda.


El libro Don Quijote
La novela Don Quijote
El hombre Don Quijote
La leyenda de Don Quijote
El cuento de Don Quijote

It all depends on how you're talking about it. There is no "true" gender for the abstract concept of a specific book. Commonly, the noun defining the gender is assumed and left out in a lot of Spanish phrases. In the examples you see, the assumed noun is probably "libro." This is similar to how "hora" is assumed when you say "Son las doce" to tell the time

This is the answer. What the writer is thinking about: "(el libro) Don Quijote fue escrito...", or "(la novela) Don Quijote fue escrita...". Look around in the context to see if you can find clues for what the writer was thinking about, but left implicit.

I'm native spanish, so cannot point out the rule in a grammar book but I am positive about what I'll say.
When you say "Don Quijote fue escrito", strangely enough you are not referencing "el libro de ..." (masculine) nor "la novela de ..." (femenine) but the name itself and Don Quijote is masculine. The same way you can say "Parque Jurásico fue rodado ..." which means "(the movie named) Jurasic Park was filmed ..." While "película", movie is femenine, "Parque Jurásico" is a "Parque", a Park, therefore masculine, and is not ackward.
When you think about movie or book titles though, some of them sound awkward. You don't say "Los Vengadores fueron rodados ...", (The movie) The Avengers was filmed, it sounds awkward, like a joke, like the avengers themselves were being forced to roll (to film and to roll are both "rodar"). Or "Cómo dejar a tu novio en 10 días fue rodado ..." this title is not referencing a specific person or object, so a native spanish wouldn't say it like this, rather "La película titulada 'Cómo dejar a tu novio en 10 días' fue rodada ...".
Is actually not so confusing if you think it like this: there are many ways to reference a given thing and they can vary with gender. You can say "Esta persona estaba callada", This person was silent. And the person you are refererring to could be a male. And a sentence with the same meaning "Este individuo estaba callado", This individual was silent, also does not specify this individual gender. But if you say "Juan estaba callado" what you have there to gender decline is just "Juan", not an "individuo" not a "persona".
Just decline what's in the sentence.

Could it be that the gender of a title is the gender of the implied category, except if the title is a singular noun phrase, it's simply the gender of that noun phrase?

@LoverofStructure, in cases where you can apply a gender to the title, like Don Quijote you are free to use the title or reference it by the category but to do the latter you need to add it, like "La novela de Don Quijote fue escrita..." in cases that's non-sensical to add a genre to the title like "Los Vengadores" or "Como perder a un chico en 10 días" you forcibly need to add the category explcitly, again depending on what you add you use one gender or another like película (femenine) or largometraje (masculine) which is a synonym
